# Decrypting data in SQL Server and pushing to a view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to join a few different tables where most of the keys for which I would join are encrypted.

I want to decrypt the columns, join the tables and then push to a view.

Here is what my current query looks like:

```
OPEN symmetric KEY decryption_key decryption BY password = 'password';

CREATE VIEW new_view 
AS
    SELECT 
        id,  
        yearid, 
        quarterid,  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), Decryptbykey(accountno)) AS 'AccountNo', 
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), Decryptbykey(firstname)) AS 'FirstName', 
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), Decryptbykey(lastname)) AS 'LastName', 
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), Decryptbykey(dateofbirth)) AS 'DateOfBirth', 
    FROM   
        table1 
    JOIN 
        table2 ON table1.AccountNo = table2.AccountNo
```

The error I get is:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPEN'

I can't seem how to decrypt data and push it in to a view. I have tried multiple combinations. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just in the post - the script it is spelled correctly.

Comment: You might need a `GO` between opening the key and the view creation

Comment: Did you close symmetric key after open it?

Comment: I might be confused, but my understanding is Sql Server will handle the decryption behind the scenes so you do not need to decrypt. That is usually the point of encryption so you cannot decrypt. Are you trying to show the decrypted data in the view? Example There is almost no way to see the SSN on the servers at my work, for a reason.

Comment: The `CREATE VIEW` statement needs to be the first statement in a batch. So as Xedni pointed out, you would need a GO in between the two statements. I would expect another error though, since your `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` clause seems correct. 

In any case, what you want to do can't be done the way you are writing it. The key won't be open in the view by simply opening it before defining the view. You can't open the key inside the view either.

Comment: This link proposes a solution based on an assymetric key: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3081/using-views-to-expose-encrypted-data-in-sql-server/. I'm adding it here, because the answer to your question is no, can't be done (with a symmetric key), and I'd rather not repeat what somebody else already explained so thoroughly. It is convoluted, sure, but that's if you persist on doing this from a view.

Answer (score 1):

As @TT mentioned, you need a `GO` before `CREATE VIEW`. That's why the syntax error.  To create the view you don't the key to be open. So `CREATE VIEW` should work ok.  To **execute** the view you need to have the key open:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY decryption_key decryption BY password = 'password';
SELECT * FROM new_view;
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY decryption_key;
```

The key remains open for the rest of the connection session.